# Calcular input com formatação (mascara)

Tags: jquery, maskmoney

Possuo 2 inputs, quantidade e valor.

O input valor está usando o plugin [Jquery MaskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/)

o mesmo está configurado da seguinte maneira:

```
$('.money').maskMoney(
{
    allowNegative: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    affixesStay: false
});
```

O que faz a sua formatação ficar da seguinte forma : 1.000,00

Mas meu calculo não está conseguindo calcular quando está na casa de milhares

```
var $valor = $('#Valor'),
    $quantidade = $('#Quantidade'),
    resultado = 0;

resultado = (parseFloat($valor.replace(",", ".")) * parseInt($quantidade));
$('#Total').val(result.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A biblioteca que você utiliza tem o método `.maskMoney('unmasked')` para extrair o valor como *float*, que você poderá utilizar pra calcular o total.

```js
$(function(){
  var valor = $('#valor');
  var quantidade = $('#quantidade');
  var total = $('#total');
  var valorTotal = 0;

  $('.money').maskMoney({
    allowNegative: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    affixesStay: false
  })
  .maskMoney('mask'); // aplicar máscara imediatamente
  
  valorTotal = valor.maskMoney('unmasked')[0] * parseInt(quantidade.val());
  total.val(valorTotal.toFixed(2)).maskMoney('mask');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="valor" class="money" value="1000.00"/>
<input type="text" id="quantidade" value="3"/>
<input type="text" id="total" class="money"/>
```